# How to dynamically update data in a text file from a python code?

Tags: python

I am writing a code to create a UI in PyQt. How can I store the data dynamically into a text file from there?

Comment: I'm afraid this is much too broad a question for us to be able to give you any help... Is there any way you can narrow the scope of this question so that we can assist you?

Comment: Open the file using `text = open('file_name.txt', 'a')` , Here 'a' stands for append so your file would not be overridden again and again, TO write the data use `text.write("Hi!")` and after writing any desired no of lines close the file as `text.close()` and you are done, Kindly refer to documentation. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: I think this question is pretty broad. When do you want to write to a file? What do you want to write?
If you have some sort of event firing off that creates an update, why not just do basic file writing operations on catching that event?

Comment: Thanks.....tried text = open('file_name.txt', 'a'). How can I clear the text when a new text is written and how can I make it appear in a fixed position of a text file?